# Unicorn can redirect after login in development but can't in production

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn

I have a typical rails application with devise.

When I authorize on dev environment (RAILS_ENV='development') everything is fine. But when I try to do this on production, it fails.

log/production.log:

`2015-12-04T08:26:38+00:00 [ INFO] 16874 : Started POST "/users/sign_in" for <1.3.3.7> at 2015-12-04 08:26:38 +0000
2015-12-04T08:26:38+00:00 [ INFO] 16874 : Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML
2015-12-04T08:26:38+00:00 [ INFO] 16874 :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"<E2><9C><93>", "authenticity_token"=>"psp/gYbp0g4qjasdfadsfasKehDo5kTN3bu2U=", "user"=>{"email"=>"someemail", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
2015-12-04T08:26:38+00:00 [ INFO] 16874 : Redirected to http://<1.2.3.4>:3000/videos`

unicorn log:

`I, [2015-12-04T08:26:38.345655 #16874]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
E, [2015-12-04T08:27:39.128909 #16860] ERROR -- : worker=0 PID:16874 timeout (61s > 60s), killing
E, [2015-12-04T08:27:39.136372 #16860] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 16874 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=0
I, [2015-12-04T08:27:39.137276 #16860]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...`

I guess it means that controller processed request and tried to send 302 to client, but for some reason didn't find it and failed by timeout.

I have no idea what may be wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: looks like network timeout. Do you hard code any addresses that only the dev environment can access?

Comment: Wow! You were almost right, I ran it on one machine, but use some different service, and it's development address works fine, and prod one moved. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can add an answer yourself so other users coming here can benefit!

Answer (score 0):

So, as @richfisher said and were almost right, I had a service, that I used inside login, and that service was gone in prod environment, but remained in dev one. So I did http request, it returned nothing (literally nothing, no 404, no 500, I guess there is some web server is still on that host), so I couldn't login and failed by timeout.